# SQLite Table created, how to input data?

Tags: android, sqlite

This a probably a really easy answer but for some reason no one explains properly how to do it, Ok So I've created my table database in SQLite and now i want to input some data into it...

Something like this for example, actually exactly this:

```
   CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
  `id_route` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_stop` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `days` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `schedule` (`id_route`, `id_stop`, `time`, `days`) VALUES
(1, 1, '05:00:00', 'all'),
(1, 1, '06:00:00', 'all'),
(1, 1, '09:35:00', 'all but weekdays'),
(1, 2, '07:00:00', 'all'),
```

How do you do this in android SQL?

```
public what definition?(){
ContentValues values3 = new ContentValues();
                values3.put(id_route, id_stop, "07.29", "day1");
                values3.put(id_route, id_stop, "07.41", "day1");
                values3.put(id_route, id_stop, "08.05", "day1");
                values3.put(id_route, id_stop, "08.12", "day1");
                values3.put(id_route, id_stop, "08.18", "day1");
                long id3 = db.insert(schedule table, null, values3);
return?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code for creating and adding the values into the table. i put here only creating table and adding values into table.

```
Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase db;     
private final String DB_NAME = "database_name";
private final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private final String TABLE_NAME = "database_table";
private final String TABLE_ROW_ID = "id";
private final String TABLE_ROW_ONE = "table_row_one";
private final String TABLE_ROW_TWO = "table_row_two";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;

    CustomSQLiteOpenHelper helper = new CustomSQLiteOpenHelper(context);
    this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}





public void addRow(String rowStringOne, String rowStringTwo)
{

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, rowStringOne);
    values.put(TABLE_ROW_TWO, rowStringTwo);


    try{db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to put more than 2 values in the values.put() with this example?

Comment: No, it is not possible. you can do the concatenation, like
values.put(TABLE_ROW_ONE, "one" + "Two");

Comment: I see, sorry if im not understanding this correctly but I thought that this would be considered as a row: values3.put(id_route, id_stop, "07.29", "day1"); and the column would be the corresponding table: db.insert(TABLE_MENU, null, values);
If this is the case then how do you make sure that more than two parameters are in the same row?

Comment: AFAIK, it's possible to put only possible to put one value at a time in values.put();.

Comment: wolverine please see my comment below to see if I've understood this correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
public void addContact() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();     
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values3.put(id_route, id_stop, "07.29", "day1");
            values3.put(id_route, id_stop, "07.41", "day1");               
    db.insert(TABLE_MENU, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

Comment: I get this error: The method put(String, String) in the type ContentValues is not applicable for the arguments (String, int, String)

Comment: your error tell you the problem.. check the number of parameter passed in...and the type as well...

Answer (score 2):

ContentValues.put syntax is like put(key, value) where key is field name.
So you should insert data like this:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("id_route", 1);
cv.put("days", "day1");
db.insert("table1", null, cv);
```

You can read about ContentValues [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html)